# Java, странные результаты сравнения

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static PrintStream out = System.out;

    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float a = 0, b = 0;
        boolean d, l;
        if (in.hasNextInt())
            b = in.nextInt();
        d = (-3.0 <= b) && (b <= 5.0);
        l = (9.0 <= b) && (b <= 15.0);
        out.print(d || l);
    }

}
```

результат для 6.2 - d = true(??), l = false

почему?(

Comment: прежде всего стоит проверить заходишь ли ты в условие _if (in.hasNextInt())_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**hasNextInt** - return true if and only if this scanner's next token is a valid int value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt())

На входе 6.2 - очевидно не является целым числом, поэтому данный метод возвращает `false`, и у переменной `b` остается значение *0*

Далее в условиях:

```
-3.0 <= 0 && 0 <= 5    // очевидно true  
 9.0 <= 0 && 0 <= 15.0 // false
```

Comment: то есть надо использовать аналогичный метод для float? Спасибо)

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko, вообще стоит использовать метод для того типа, который нужен. В данном случае, да можно использовать [hasNextFloat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextFloat())

Comment: святой вы человек:). Спасибо)